# Where does the docker the overlay network first created, on manger or worker?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have came across a question in docker associate exam test, I found two different answer of the same question on two different platform. So, I wanted to know what is really true about creating overlay network.

[image]

One platform mentioned **option#1** as correct answer, Overlay network is first created on manger nodes then they are created on the worker nodes once a task is scheduled on the specific worker node.

Another platform mentioned **option#3** as correct answer, overlay network are created on all cluster nodes when you create an overlay network.

I found details about ingress network on docker documentation that ingress network is getting created automatically when create a swarm or join any node to the swarm. But I could not find more details on docker website which can answer this question. Any suggestion or reference will be appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option#1 is correct. A network is initialy created on manager nodes and will be created on a worker node once a container attached to this network is deployed on it.

Try it yourself:

- create an overlay network on one of the a manager nodes
- inspect all manager nodes and verify that the network exist on them
- inspect all worker nodes and verify that the network does not exist on them
- deploy a service using a placement constraint that forces the task (which creates the container) to be executed on a particular node; then inspect the worker nodes again to verify that the network is only created on the worker nodes matching the placement constraint